# 2x col-xs-6 getting into new line instead of sharing the row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am playing with Bootstrap 4, and I am trying to do a really straight-forward task, 2x `col-xs-6` inside a row. It pushes the values to a new line :S.

```
 <div class="row">
     <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6">
           hehe
     </div>
     <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6">
           hehe
     </div>
 </div>
```

I also tried but no luck either.

```
 <div class="col-xs-12">
     <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6">
           hehe
     </div>
     <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6">
           hehe
     </div>
 </div>
```

---

Instead of

```
|   6   |   6   |
```

I am getting

```
|       12       |
|       12       |
```

Aren't they supposed to work? What am I missing?

Comment: Is this bootstrap 4? Also, I tried narrowing the width of my browser, and then it hits 570px, it pushes them in 2 lines.

Comment: There are no `col-xs-` classes in the newest version of Bootstrap 4. Now you should use `col-6` instead of `col-xs-6`.

Comment: @makshh Oh.. Thanks a lot! Saved me from more hours to be wasted...

Comment: And if you use `col-6` you don't need `col-sm-6`, but probably you know it :)

Comment: @MichaelCoker But it's supposed to be side by side <=576px. 'col-xs-6' doesn't apply any styles to the div in bootstrap 4

Comment: @MichaelCoker According to the question being asked. Read the original question again. senty want's two equal sized columns inside the "xs" viewport.

Comment: @senty were you able to find a solution for this ?

Answer (score 5):

`col-xs-*` no longer eixsts in bootstrap4. Just use `col-6` instead.

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-6">.col-6</div>
  <div class="col-6">.col-6</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

[http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/](http://Bootstrap%204%20doc)

> Each tier of classes scales up, meaning if you plan on setting the
>   same widths for xs and sm, you only need to specify xs.

So it can be a little confusing because the documentation still refers to "xs" but that is probably more in relation to the breakpoints.

Comment: They updated documentation, but not the examples. http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/#grid-options

Answer (score -1):

The container of a `<div class="col-...">` should be a `<div class="row">`.

```
.row
  .col-xs-6
  .col-xs-6
```

---

Here's the docs:
http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Comment: Thats not the answer. I am not even using bootstrap 3. The right answer is given in the comments. I wished you took the time to read maybe not my question, but at least the snippets... It shows what you exactly written as answer.